# Scene View and Game View are Different (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity and I don't know a lot about how it works, so I don't really know what I could've done or what could be different from the default settings, so I hope this picture is sufficient.

I played around with the light GameObject a lot and it didn't do anything as far as I know. I also moved the camera around and it looks the same in all lighting and viewing angles.

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TXxC.png)

Comment: The difference looks to be lighting. The below pic being much brighter.  Iooks like the editor has lighting turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I had a massive semi-transparent white panel UI open, blocking the camera at all times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).